# How to code schema.org for national searches?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

My client would like their company name (the run throughout the US) to come up in a goolge search based on the zip code a user puts in the google. I figured it must be schema.org..I have found a similar site and this is the code source I found:

```
 <!-- Top Bar -->
        <div id="top_toolbar" class="clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breadcrumbContainer">
     <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <a href="/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">TITLE HERE</span> </a>   </div>
            <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <span>   <a href="/TITLEHERE" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">TITLEHERE </span> </a>   </span></div>
            <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <span>   <a href="/Something/In" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">In </span> </a>   </span></div>


</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I was to google search "Something in 49117" this is the source code:

```
 <div id="top_toolbar" class="clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breadcrumbContainer">
     <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <a href="/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">TITLEHERE</span> </a>   </div>
            <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <span>   <a href="/TITLEHERE" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">TITLEHERE </span> </a>   </span></div>
            <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <span>   <a href="/TITLEHERE/In" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">In </span> </a>   </span></div>
            <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">  <span>   <a href="/AutoTransport/In/49117" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">49117 </span> </a>   </span></div>
    <div class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">   <a href="/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Instant Quote</span> </a>   </div>

</div>
```